# Why is the return "Hey Mickey" different when the parameter is set to "Mickey"?

Tags: javascript

```
function hi(cartoon_character) {
 if (cartoon_character == { name: 'Mickey' }) {
   return 'Hey Mickey'
 } else {
   return 'Hey Mouse'
 }
}

document.write(hi({ name: 'Mickey' }));
```

why the result is **"Hey Mouse"**
should be "**Hey Mickey"**

Comment: It's kind of a subject where you should know more about javascript but you can do `if(cartoon_character.name === 'Mickey')` to check.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300116/2358409

Comment: but why yes, when I fill the parameters with other text. For example name: 'ABCD', the result is still Mickey. while else is not executed

Answer (score 1):

Here you are comparing the memory locations(references) and hence the result is always Hey Mouse. A quick workaround could be:

```js
function hi(cartoon_character) {
     if (JSON.stringify(cartoon_character) ===
     JSON.stringify({ name: 'Mickey' })) {
       return 'Hey Mickey'
     } else {
       return 'Hey Mouse'
     }
    }
    
 console.log( hi({name: 'Mickey'}) )
```

For better understanding have a look [https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f#:~:text=Comparing%20objects%20is%20easy%2C%20use,obj2](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f#:%7E:text=Comparing%20objects%20is%20easy%2C%20use,obj2))%3B%20would%20return%20false.

Comment: This is somewhat static approach , but if it confirmed the object has name key , then you can try this : function hi(cartoon_character) {
     var ourObject = {name: 'Mickey'}
    
        if(cartoon_character['name'] === ourObject['name']) {
            return 'Hey Mickey'
        }
        else {
            return 'Hey Mouse'
        }
    
}

Comment: sorry what if like this, my answer is wrong?

`function hi(cartoon_character) {
  if (cartoon_character.name == 'Mickey') {
    return 'Hey Mickey'
   } else {
    return 'Hey Mouse'
   }
 }
 $("#fixed-soal-no4").html(hi({ name: 'Mickey' }));`

Comment: Function you have written is absolutely fine , no issues in that

Comment: thank you, but I want to ask one more thing. Is what I wrote efficient? or is there a more efficient way? thank you @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi

Comment: This seems fine to me . Also , if you are ok with the solution provided by me , would you mind accepting the answer and giving upvote for better visibility.